# How to differenciate text from data in bytes from a TCP socket in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp, tcpclient

First I receive all data that's coming from the server:

```
server_response = b''
buffer = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
while buffer:
    server_response += buffer
    buffer = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
```

Now I have all the bytes in the server_response var but I'm not sure how to process it. Say that the server is sending something with the following structure:

```
FILE file_name file_size data\n
```

I can't .decode() everything at once because "data" is a file of any format so I'll just get an error.

I know that the full server response has 4 "words" separated by spaces and the message ends with `\n`. My problem here is that I have to parse some part of that  into a string, and the rest into a file, and I'm not sure how to do that since they're all together in the same bytearray variable.

Comment: It's much easier to make a TCP protocol when you define a predetermined length as the "header" (a.k.a where your FILE, file_name, and file_size are determined). Then retrieve the data as a separate recv. Also do note that recv() isn't guaranteed to give you that much bytes, so you have to make sure you're iterating to get the total data.

Comment: I don't really get to choose that though, I have to work with that format. If it were like you said, how would you read the size? I don't know how to take the server_response var and read it up until the first space for example. If someone can tell me that then I'll probably be able to do the rest on my own

Comment: In that case, you could probably do a byte to byte comparison for a space character. Maybe you could do something like `bytes.split(b" ", 3)` to split up your variables. This, of course, will assume that spaces don't exist in any of your predetermined variables.

Comment: @NinjaKitty I was able to separate the file details from the data, but since I actually have multiple files in the same command I need to know where the data ends. I can use file_size for that. Is there a way to cut the bytearray using the file_size?

Comment: Slicing the bytearray syntax is the same as slicing a string, bytes, or a list. You can use the same `object[:int]` syntax for your use case.